# Is there any posssible way to remotely control my own android device using terminal?

Tags: command-line, android, remote-access

Is there any posssible way to remotely control my own android device using terminal ?

I will be using it for completely ethical purposes. I just want to control my android phone using terminal.

Comment: With or without USB connection? I had a question to trigger some sort of alarm on my phone vie bluetooth when a program on the server has finished, so I don't have to check the server every few minutes. Regrettably, there was little response.

Answer (score 1):

You can install an ssh client on the android device,
but i think you want to simulate mouse moves and clicks,
those are a little more complicated,

I think you would need adb tools to do that
There is a java tool called **adbcontrol**, its gui, but you can get
the code and make something for terminal to your purposes